# How to set up WiFi Access Point by connecting to another WiFi?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

My apartment provide us Internet access through WiFi, not Ethernet cable. Their WiFi has an annoying sign-on system that require me to record each of my devices' MAC periodcally.

I want to use a special router to create my own WiFi and only need to register my router's MAC into their system. Is this achievable? If yes, I also want this device fast enough (~500 Mbps).

NOTE: I am not looking for repeater or extender, since they only bridge the signal and still need me to connect to my apartment's DHCP service to register my devices.

Comment: This depends on how long the captive portal holds the Mac address pair for the session. Does it have an activity timer that auto logs you out? The speed is determined by the access point in your apartment.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I don't mind the period to register my MAC as long as only the router's MAC is needed. I just do not want to register every device I own repeatedly.

Comment: You can use DD-wrt routers to do what you are trying to do. Just make sure you get a router with two physical wireless radios. You don't want to repeat it. You would put the first radio on client, then the second in AP mode on a non-conflicting channel. Client mode would have one ip/Mac pair one the apt network, and you wouldn't have to re register all the devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most consumer grade routers will not have the function you seek. Your going to need a new router. You can take a peek at the compatibility list for dd-wrt here: https://wikidevi.com/wiki/List_of_DD-WRT_firmware_supported_devices

If you don't feel comfortable installing third party firmware on a router. You can find them with dd-wrt pre-installed. Just search for dd-wrt router in your favorite online retailer. Some Buffalo models have custom versions pre-installed.

I have had terrible experiences with atheros, broadcom & ralink based routers trying to bridge & repeat on the same interface. Just get a dd-wrt router with two physical interfaces. (Two wireless radios). A good for instance is the Netgear wndr4300 (version 4)